# Update state of corresponding state items in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am still a beginner in React/Redux at work.
This what i am trying to do:

I have a documents state which has list of documents a user might have

```
hasDocuments: (
  state,
  action: PayloadAction<{ documents: any }>,
) => {
  state.hasDocuments = true;
  state.documents = { ...action.payload };
}

updateDocumentStatus: (
  state,
  action: PayloadAction<{ id: any; status: any }>,
) => {
  //want to update status of each document here. Not sure how to this
},
```

I am also listening to events so i can update my state like this:

```
        case 'documentViewed': {
          dispatch(
            updateDocumentStatus({
              id: data.id,
              status: { hasViewed: data.hasViewed },
            }),
          );
          break;
        }
```

However i am unsure on how to get the corresponding id from `state.documents` and update the same in my `updateDocumentStatus` method

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] so we can see the complete reducer and/or state slice code, including what the initial value is and the action payloads so we can see how the state updates over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the shape of your `documents` object but as per my understanding you would just have to "mutate" the `documents` object using the `id` as key.

I'm asuming that you want to add the status to the document, but you can add any value depending of how `documents` looks like.

```
updateDocumentStatus: (
  state,
  action: PayloadAction<{ id: any; status: any }>,
) => {
  // RTK allows you to "mutate" the state thanks to the Immer library
  state.documents[action.payload.id] = { ...state.documents[action.payload.id], status: action.payload.status };
},
```